# creating a character array malloc

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to read data values from an SD card. I have a function that returns a character and a -1 when it reaches the end of file. I want to store each character in an array.

I initialize it the storage array as such :

```
char* storage = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE));
```

however when i print the values out, i don't get the proper data. However if I change it to:

```
int* storage = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE));
```

it works.

Am i initializing the pointer array wrong?

Comment: how are you printing ?

Comment: It seems like it returns `int` and not `char` since `char` is not specified to even support negative numbers.

Comment: read the documentation for the function. Post that description along with the code you are using to call the function and to print out the results.

Comment: there is some other mistake because first initialization is correct

Comment: short int alt_up_sd_card_read(short int file_handle);
/* Read a single character from the given file. Return -1 if at the end of a file. Any other negative number
 * means that the file could not be read. A number between 0 and 255 is an ASCII character read from the SD Card. */

Answer (score -1):

My mistake, I should've checked the return function of the file:

```
short int alt_up_sd_card_read(short int file_handle);
```

/* Read a single character from the given file. Return -1 if at the end of a file. Any other negative number
 * means that the file could not be read. A number between 0 and 255 is an ASCII character read from the SD Card. */

So i should be allocating short int instead of char. Thanks.

Comment: no, you should be allocating `char` or `unsigned char`. You are doing something wrong either in the code that stores the values in the array, or the code that prints the values.